# Do $P(0)$ and $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ yield $P(5)$ without an axiom of induction?

Tags: logic, induction, peano-axioms

As I understand it, Peano arithmetic needs the axiom of induction to prevent non-standard models of the natural numbers.

Given $P(0)$ and $P(n)\implies P(n+1) \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ I can apply modus ponens to get $P(1)$ and again to get $P(2)$. After 5 iterations, I should have deduced $P(5)$. Is this reasoning correct?

It seems the important part of the induction axiom is that it asserts $P(n)$ for all $n$ in the model, where without this axiom we could have elements not reachable from $0$ by iterated succession.

Does this mean that for any *particular* "ordinary" natural number that can be obtained by writing $S$ sufficiently many times in my formula, I can deduce $P(S(S(...S(0)))$ without appealing to the axiom of induction?

Comment: What exactly are you given besides $P(0)$? Are you given that $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ *for all $n\ge0$*?

Comment: Yes @GregMartin I will add the quantifier in my post.

Comment: Yes, repeating iterations a finite number of times does not necessarily use the inductive axiom. Induction is still important, though.

Comment: Thank you @LucienJaccon. You have answered my question. I am aware that induction is important, but I wanted to clarify this for myself.

Comment: Yes, Induction is only an "infinite" Modus Ponens.

Comment: You accepted an incorrect answer by DC. *Bram28* gave you the correct answer so far. If you want to learn more, feel free to ping me.

Comment: @user21820 Could you please elaborate? I'm afraid I don't think I can judge which answer is correct. What do you think needs to be corrected? I want to make sure I don't have incorrect knowledge about this topic.

Comment: Please come to the [Basic Math chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics) and request access, and then ping me here again, because I cannot find your user on SE chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does this mean that for any *particular* "ordinary" natural number that can be obtained by writing $S$ sufficiently many times in my formula, I can deduce $P(S(S(...S(0)))$ without appealing to the axiom of induction?

Yes, you can. To be exact, if you have

$$P(0)$$

and

$$\forall n (P(n) \to P(s(n)))$$

then you can prove $P(S(S(...S(0)))$ without the axiom of induction.

Indeed, even if the axiom of induction would be assumed to be false, i.e. if you also have:

$$\neg ((P(0) \land \forall n (P(n) \to P(s(n)))) \to \forall n \ P(n))$$

you can still infer $P(S(S(...S(0)))$

And this isn't because you can now suddenly prove a contradiction, because as you point out, there are non-standard models in which the axiom of induction is false, but where $P(0)$ and $\forall n (P(n) \to P(s(n)))$ are still true. No, it's simply because you can keep instantiating the $\forall n (P(n) \to P(s(n)))$ to get $P(s(0))$, $P(s(s(0)))$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean that for any *particular* "ordinary" natural number
> that can be obtained by writing $S$ sufficiently many times in my
> formula, I can deduce $P(S(S(...S(0)))$ without appealing to the axiom
> of induction

That is actually the logical equivalent of the axiom of induction. Essentially, this axiom is used to rule out the existence disconnected subsets of N that are inaccessible from $0$ by repeated succession.

In general, if $f: X\to X$, $~x_0 \in X~$ and $~X=\{x_0,f(x_0), f(f(x_0)), \cdots \}$, then induction can be said to hold on $(X,f,x_0)$, where $f$ is the "successor function" on $X$ and $x_0$ is the "first element" of $X$.

$~~~~~~~\forall P\subset X:[x_0 \in P~\land~\forall a\in P: [ f(a)\in P] \implies P=X]$

Available on request, the formal proof (228 lines) is too long to post here. (I am told by moderators not to have links to proofs in an answer. I think I can post a link in a comment if requested.)